Is the wording of the guideline on providing an answer and soliciting more opposite the intent of the guideline?
The guidelines include:

General guidelines for all questions:

Should include research: What ideas have you considered, or what information have you already looked at or failed to find?


and

To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
avoid asking subjective questions where …

your
answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”


The second item is frequently interpreted as meaning that "offering your own answers and asking for more is specifically prohibited."
I take this interpretation to be specifically contrary to the first item.
I take to be the intent of the second item to be: "Do not ask subjective questions, including subjective questions which ask for subjective preferences between a variety of equally possible answers."
Which could be worded to fit the bullet-point style as:

To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
avoid asking subjective questions where …

your current preference is provided along with the question, and you ask for answers in the form of other preferences: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”


Should the wording of the second item be changed to clarify its intent and avoid the impression of a prohibition against listing what ideas you have considered, or what information you have already looked at?

The unfortunate truth is we can't change those parts of the Help Center page — they're a network-wide resource.
However, there is a significant difference between the two that only works if the community moderates the questions properly.
The admonition about research should be interpreted as...

Tell us what you tried and clearly explain why it doesn't work for you. In this way, your efforts become limitations and conditions that help respondents narrow their answers productively.

In other words, the OP is explaining why they are NOT answers. Compare this to the admonition not to include your own answers and expect more, which means you're really just brainstorming and you haven't dismissed what answers you've come up with — just in case none of us can provide any better solution.
Embracing the former leads to a single best answer.
Ignoring the latter leads to an open-ended all-answers-have-equal-value question.
Holding the OP to these conditions (which I'm frequently chastised for doing) is what leads to higher quality questions.
P.S., Think about how SciFi.SE has become 95% a "help me identify this story I've forgotten" site. If we fail to hold to the above standards, we'll rapidly become a "give me some ideas for my story" site. If that's what we want... but it isn't worldbuilding.
